# comparing a matrix and a vector

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Is there an easier vectorized way to achieve the same result as this?

```
import numpy as np
tempY = np.zeros((10,10))
y = np.array([0,0,2,3,4,5,5,8,8,2]).reshape(10,1)
for index in range(y.size):
    tempY[y[index].squeeze(), index] = 1

print(tempY)
```

output:

```
[[1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` question, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass it as rows, columns to index and replace the values :

```
tempY[y.ravel(), np.arange(y.size)] = 1

tempY

array([[1., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```